# Why does an online stock broker need to know information about my current salary?

Tags: brokerage

I'm in the process of opening an account with TD Ameritrade, and they've asked for proof of employment that includes my current salary.

Why would they need to know my current salary? Especially since all the employment contracts I've seen have had clauses that say the salary and all remuneration is confidential.

Related: [Why does an online stock broker need to know information about my place of employment?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/why-does-an-online-stock-broker-need-to-know-information-about-my-place-of-emplo) but the broker is going further by asking not just for place of enrolment but also for current salary.

Comment: Are you opening a margin account?

Comment: @user662852 yes, although their description of the kind of margin one can use conspicuously excludes uncovered options.

Comment: "Especially since all the employment contracts I've seen have had clauses that say the salary and all remuneration is confidential." - I don't know your jurisdiction, but even in the notoriously labor-hostile United States, this is illegal.

Comment: Are you asking about legal reasons, or why such laws exist?

Comment: @Kevin It could simply be misreading the contract. That information *is confidential* from the perspective of the company to the employee. HR can't tell anyone else what OP makes, but OP can tell anyone freely

Comment: @Kevin I asked one HR department about why that clause is present, and they said it's so that I don't tell my colleagues - which sounds like a reasonable thing to do, because if everyone knew exactly how much everyone else makes, there might be resentment. On the other hand, the clause clearly says that it is *me* who cannot reveal the numbers. The exact words in one of the contracts are "You are required to keep your salary, any Merit Increments and/or Performance Bonus paid to you confidential at all times."

Comment: @Allure: In the US, telling your colleagues about your salary or other compensation is explicitly protected as a form of labor organizing. If it "causes resentment," then that's management's problem. See the NLRB's [discussion of concerted activity](https://www.nlrb.gov/about-nlrb/rights-we-protect/the-law/employees/concerted-activity). Your local jurisdiction might differ from the US, of course.

Comment: Do brokerages based in your home jurisdiction ask this question?  Maybe you are simply unable to both comply with your contract and use the services of a US based brokerage

Comment: @Kevin You are, of course, correct. However, such protections have very small teeth. I believe the penalty is backpay for individuals who discover they are being unfairly undercompensated. So it is still in your company's interest to have these policies, even if they are illegal.

Comment: @BlackThorn: I wanted to ensure that OP is aware of the law and their rights. What they do about it (if anything) is up to them.

Comment: @Allure If you couldn't discuss working conditions with your colleagues (and compensation is *definitely* part of working conditions), how could you organize together to demand better working conditions? If resentment is appropriate, then employees *should* be resentful and that *should* trigger them to demand better working conditions. That's how labor is supposed to work and any HR person who doesn't understand that is terrible at their job.

Comment: @BlackThorn The point is not some penalty for unfairly undercompensating people. The point is for employees to be able to work together to demand better compensation if that's what they want to do. They may or may not want do that, but management is prohibited by law from trying to stop them. If Alice wants to tell Bob her salary so Bob can demand a higher salary if he's paid less, then management can't stop Alice and Bob from working together that way.

Comment: @Kevin an employment contract can not make anything illegal.  You are not going to jail for violating any of the terms in your contract.  At worse, your employer could sue you for damages.

Comment: @Kevin if management wanted to enforce its contract (they don't) then it is hard to see how telling your broker your salary is part of labor organizing.  If you tell your broker your salary you are violating your contract and management can sue you for damages ($0.00 - might as well save yourself the legal costs and write them out a check now).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz considering that one of the primary purposes of HR is to represent management any HR person who doesn't pretend to not understand is terrible at their job.

Comment: @emory: If they cared (they almost certainly don't), they would not sue you. They would "write you up" for "insubordination" and/or fire you. Then you'd have to sue them for wrongful termination, which is an extreme uphill climb in the US because of at-will employment (except in Montana, where they'd have to characterize it as for-cause termination - but they'd just say you breached your contract).

Comment: @emory One primary purpose of HR is to *protect* management from breaking the law. Intimidating people into not engaging in legally protected activity is unlawful. Sadly, some HR people do think they're helping management by doing that, but competent management stomps out cancers like that because they are incredibly corrosive to a smoothly functioning company.

Comment: @Kevin exactly, it is not illegal because effectively there are no rules.  Anything goes.

Comment: @emory: There is a difference between "unenforceable" and "not illegal." Every now and then, a company is dumb and writes down its illegal workplace practices in a discoverable medium, and somebody sues the pants off them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[Anti Money Laundering (AML)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/aml.asp)**

In our current political climate, there is a huge amount of pressure to enact strong AML controls to prevent tax evasion, funding of terrorists and circumventing of economic sanctions.

The first line of defense most financial institutes have against aiding such activities is called Know Your Client.

**[Know Your Client (KYC)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/k/knowyourclient.asp)**

Basic information about each client is gathered at the client onboarding stage, and is updated at regular intervals to ensure adequate checks are applied to your account.

Financial institutes will need a basic understanding of your finances, and your family/political/etc. connections.

Banks need to know for example, if they should investigate further when $100,000 USD is deposited into a trading account for instance. If the account was held by Warren Buffet, for example, they would conclude that it is chump change and probably completely normal.

However, if a seriously in debt student deposited a "phat stack of green" into his trading account. An investigation would be launched into the source of these funds.

During the investigation, a bank may find that the money comes from:

- Local school teacher turned meth kingpin
- Kim Jung Un
- Osama bin Laden
- Untaxed income (such as your freelance assassin gig)
- A job you can work from home, where you forward checks to different addresses

**Financial Regulators**

What you may not know is that a financial institute can very often fall under the regulation of multiple national financial regulators, simply by:

- Having a presence in that country
- Hiring a national from that country
- Doing business with someone with ties to that country
- Existing on the same planet as that country

source: My Annual AML/KYC training

Comment: Fun fact: [current estimates show](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339486326_Anti-money_laundering_The_world's_least_effective_policy_experiment_Together_we_can_fix_it) that only 0.1% of fraudulent transactions are caught by KYC processes. Real criminals know numerous ways around these laws. Its the normal people who suffer the most from such bureaucracy. Adding the comment as your answer seems to imply that these processes are good because they catch criminals - they kind of don't.

Comment: @JonathanReez Doesn't surprise me at all--such measures are going to be best at catching tax cheats, not bigger fish.

Comment: @JonathanReez The purpose of the regulations is preventing crime by making it harder and more expensive. Catching a criminal is always a failure, because the crime has already happened by then.

Comment: @Jouni there’s a high cost to society from these measures, as financial transactions become more expensive and people have to waste time on paperwork. The question is if preventing some crime is worth this added friction. The regulators are never forced to produce a cost benefit analysis to justify what they’re doing, unfortunately.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, that's the wrong way to think about it. These processes force criminals to be smarter and work harder, increasing the cost and barrier of money laundering, therefore reducing the volume. It prevents ordinary criminals from doing it, only smart ones. Police arrest people they see committing murder. Very few people are caught this way, so by your logic, police shouldn't bother anybody committing murder in front of them. Would the police be as effective in that case? Your logic says yes.

Comment: @user71659 now do the other side of equation: let’s say KYC prevents $10b worth of crime per year. Does it take less than $10b worldwide to comply and enforce KYC? By how much is global trade reduced due to KYC? And the effects are compounding - if trade is reduced by 0.1% per year, that’s a 3% compounded reduction over 30 years. It’s very rare to see such calculations from police officials as they threaten their jobs.

Comment: @JonathanReez I can confidently say KYC prevents far over $10B of crime a year, since worldwide illicit drug trade in itself is a $600B a year business. Again, you're thinking in direct effects. The point of KYC is to make it harder to commit other forms of crime, since money is a key motivator. This was a famous lesson known from the prosecution of Al Capone, and was key in reducing organized crime in the US during the 1970s.

Comment: @user71659 is there a cost-benefit analysis somewhere that tries to measure direct and indirect consequences of KYC/money laundering laws on the global economy? Keep in mind that while the drug trade is $600B a year, not all of it is detrimental to the global economy, just like the sales of alcohol/cigarettes have both positive and negative effects.

Comment: @Jouni your take is smart, but Im afraid the actual purpose of the regulation is to make it harder to cheat for peasants, while clearing the path for elites.

Comment: @JonathanReez As others have noted, KYC doesn't catch fraudulent transactions, but rather prevents them locally. This will likely force criminals to other, less robust institutions with weak AML/KYC processes. Why burgle a neighbourhood watch house, when there are houses that are left unlocked? Take HSBC of 2012. Regulators found that various cartels are funneling their money laundering services through the HSBC banking network. In this case, it wasn't the KYC process at HSBC that caught the fraudulent transactions, but rather the audit that occured after it was found that HSBC has crap AML.

Answer (score 24):

Stock brokerages are required by law, in the USA at least, to collect employer information as well as income and other personal information.  You will find that all of them do this because the penalties for them are significant for non-compliance.

This is to comply with various laws that demand that they report potential conflicts of interest and tax reporting.  They are also required to ensure that your trading habits are in line with your income level.

Comment: I guess I should have said: "income and/or net worth".  But I think you meant "earned income".

Comment: @jwh20 "Ensure that your trading habits are in line with your income level" -- what does that mean? Are people with different salaries required by law to trade differently?

Comment: @ManRow It means they must monitor and flag any unexpected cash flows. We in the industry called this Anti Money Laundering or AML for short. The information collected is Know Your Client (KYC). Without proper KYC, we cannot affect AML controls. If for instance, you say you have $10k in savings and $30k income, we would flag your account if you make a $10mil purchase order on AMC.

Comment: @Aron maybe write that as an answer, it feels like it cuts closest to the heart of the question.

Comment: Also as way to combating money laundering and the financing of terrorism.

Comment: Some expensive and risky investments are restricted to high net worth investors. I assume it's because they can afford to lose what they put in, and their worth implies they have financial accumen to make an informed decision about investing.

Comment: Is there a penalty for lying to the stock broker by saying you're unemployed, assuming you don't mind dealing with a government audit where you'll tell the truth?

Answer (score 14):

> "Especially since all the employment contracts I've seen have had
> clauses that say the salary and all remuneration is confidential."

Let's assume that you have signed an agreement to not tell anybody what your income is. Taken to the extreme that would mean that you can't apply for a car loan, or a mortgage, or a credit card. All these things require you to tell them your income so that they can determine if you can afford it. Also your bank and the IRS know. Lenders sometimes require you to submit copies of tax forms, or pay stubs.

So why does your broker need to know? If you are wanting to invest in complicated markets they need to know you can afford the amount you are risking. If you are purchasing investment advice they also need to understand your entire financial situation before suggesting specific investments.

Answer (score 4):

A broken may ask you this because they want to know if you are a "Qualified" or "Accredited" investor, which includes an income test to verify. There are a number  of investments that are only offered to accredited investors, for example unregistered securities (which may be riskier).

So they probably want to flag your account as to whether these options are available to you.

[More Info on Accredited Investors](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/accreditedinvestor.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The point about AML / KYC has already been covered by @Aron but I just wanted to jump in on this point:

> Especially since all the employment contracts I've seen have had
> clauses that say the salary and all remuneration is confidential.

I suggest you re-read your employment contract.

You will find that most contracts (whether employment or otherwise) that have a confidentiality clause will be worded as follows:

*"X, Y and Z is confidential except where disclosure is required by law or disclosure to professional advisors"*.

The wording might not all be in the same clause, it might be lower down the document, but it will be there.

Confidentially cannot over-rule the law or your right to seek professional advice (i.e. accountants, lawyers etc) .  In the case of stockbrokers, KYC/AML is the law.

Comment: I re-read my employment contract and the clause you mention is not there. It should be though. I'll suggest it to HR.

Comment: HR says it's understood that the statutory law is above the employment contract, and financial advisors are statutory, so /shrug.